# Diesel migration run failed for postgresql at the first beginning

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

Following [diesel.rs quickstart](http://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started), got error:

```
#] diesel migration run
Running migration 2022-01-13-151140_create_posts
Executing migration script /Users/u/p/migrations/2022-01-13-151140_create_posts/up.sql
Failed with: Received an empty query
```

diesel --version

diesel 1.4.1

rustc --version

rustc 1.57.0 (f1edd0429 2021-11-29)

psql --version

psql (PostgreSQL) 14.1

macOS 12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sign that the sql file you edit is not in the right migration folder.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably executed

```
diesel migration generate create_rustaceans
diesel migration generate create_crates
```

twice, so you probably have two different folders in migrations with different dates. Check the old one and copy paste to the new one, then delete the old.